# CMake Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3")

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I kept on having this Error:

```
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at
  least version "3")
```

I am using Android Studio and trying to do this one:
https://github.com/hrydgard/ppsspp/wiki/Build-instructions

I followed the instructions with no mistake:

1. Downloaded the source code
2. Installed the latest Python which is version 3.8
3. Installed the latest Android Studio without internet interruption
4. Installed NDK and Cmake using SDK Manager
5. Opened the downloaded source code's folder as project in Android Studio

But I still always get that error. Thanks in advance for those who are glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I fixed it by just copying the whole Python Files (Installed Python) to where the cloned repositories are.